# Gradle dependsOn not working when called again within dependent task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I wanted to run `superParent` task in my below `build.gradle` whenever it is called.

```
task superParent {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello Super Parent Last'
    }
}

task helloParent {
    dependsOn superParent
    description 'Hello task is Dependent on helloParent Task'
    doFirst {
        println 'Hello Parent First'
    }
    doLast {
        println 'Hello Parent Last'
    }
}

task hello {
    description 'Just prints Hello..'
    dependsOn helloParent,superParent
    doFirst {
        println 'Hello First'
    }
    doLast {
        println 'Hello Last'
    }
}
```

when i execute `gradlew hello`, am getting the below output

```
> Task :superParent       
Hello Super Parent Last   

> Task :helloParent       
Hello Parent First        
Hello Parent Last         

> Task :hello             
Hello First               
Hello Last
```

The `superParent` task is not called again from the `hello` task. I am expecting an output like this

**Expected Outcome**

```
> Task :superParent       
Hello Super Parent Last   

> Task :helloParent       
Hello Parent First        
Hello Parent Last     

> Task :superParent       
Hello Super Parent Last     

> Task :hello             
Hello First               
Hello Last
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option to add a task to a DAG (directed acyclic graph - which gradle uses under the hood) more than once. A task may be added at most *once*. Hence, if you define a dependency from task `A` and `B` to `C` the order of execution might be:

- `C` -> `B` -> `A`
- `C` -> `A` -> `B`

But `C` will be run only once.